# Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https

Tags: google-chrome, https, localhost

When I debug a Visual Studio project using Chrome the browser tries to redirect to the https equivalent of my web address. I do not have SSL enabled in the web project and the start URL is the http URL.  When I debug using FireFox or IE I do not have this problem.

I did re-install Chrome which fixed the problem for a day.  Without downloading any addons the problem happened again the next day.

What is making Chrome redirect localhost to https?

Network Inspect Shows:
Request URL:data:text/html,chromewebdata
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36

No preview and no response data in those tabs.

Comment: what is Network Inspector showing ?

Comment: Network inspect doesn't show much at all.  I can't even see the URL being requested. Request URL:data:text/html,chromewebdata
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36

Comment: CHROME 63: keep scrolling for answers

Comment: By just reinstalling my chrome solves all the issues.. now my .dev and not redirecting to https anymore. I wish i would have tried that earlier.. wasted so much time..

Comment: Anyone with this problem recently, if you are trying to use `.dev` as your local doman, it's a whole new issue so I don't think any of these answers will work anymore. As of Chrome 63... "Chrome to force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS". So no more self-signed SSL certs. Apparently .dev is a real domain. Who knew.

Comment: When I upgraded from Chrome 62 to 63 on my mac, I couldn't use `.app` either. I had to use `.test`.

Comment: But while what I did is changed the domain from .app to .appp it is working fine with the chrome. Can anyone tell me about that

Comment: Was happening to me as well on Chrome 74.0.3729.131.  I have several localhost projects.  DevTools was not showing much.  But did an empty cache/hard reload from right click on refresh with dev tools up, and that allowed me to now type in https.  Somewhat related to answer below, but less steps.

Comment: For those like me who tried anything possible unsuccessfully, have a look to your web server config to check that HTTP requests are not rewrited to HTTPS (htaccess file for instance)... I feel so stupid...

Comment: It's helped me. https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

Comment: The selected answer seems out of date. I was successful at resolving this with https://stackoverflow.com/a/43354790/401735 -- which is quick and painless

Answer (score 959, accepted):

I believe this is caused by HSTS - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

If you have (developed) any other localhost sites which send a HSTS header ...

> e.g. `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload`

... then depending on the value of `max-age`, future requests to localhost will be required to be served over HTTPS.

To get around this, I did the following.

- In the Chrome *address bar* type the following:

  > `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
- At the very bottom of a page there is QUERY domain textbox - verify that localhost is known to the browser. **If it says "Not found" then this is not the answer you are looking for.**
- If it is, DELETE the localhost domain using the textbox above
- Your site should now work using plain old HTTP

This is not a permanent solution, but will at least get it working between projects. If anyone knows how to permanently exclude localhost from the HSTS list please let me know :)

---

### UPDATE - November 2017

Chrome has recently moved this setting to sit under the section

> **Delete domain security policies**

[image]

---

### UPDATE - December 2017

If you are using .dev domain see other answers below as Chrome (and others) force HTTPS via preloaded HSTS.

Comment: I tried to query for "localhost" but it says Not found

Comment: you can also try it in another browser, such as IE.

Comment: For those using Edge, clearing browsing data has the same effect.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but any idea how to resolve if, on querying localhost as per accepted answer, it does return 'not found'?  Tried everything in all comments and answers here.

Comment: I have the same issue. But this solution does not work. On "chrome://net-internals/#hsts" localhost is not found....

Comment: This is total garbage by Chrome. How do they expect us to dev locally when  they just arbitrarily start forcing you to HTTPS on your freaking localhost? I have used everything just fine for months, I log in one morning and get this crap to deal with. None of these "fixes" are working for me.

Comment: If your localhost domain is `.dev`  then I believe this is not working @Alison because as of the recent release of v.63 ... "Chrome to force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS". As such, .dev basically won't work at all anymore unless you have proper signed SSL certificate. No more self signed certificates allowed. [More details](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

Comment: If you're using Laravel valet change your parked working directory TLD by `valet domain test`

Comment: If it helps anyone, I turned off the capturing events and it didn't work for me. I had to go back to the page again with capturing events running in order for it to work.

Comment: The "Delete" button does not do anything, as I reported [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-admins/QncNmCgdYA0). After clicking "Delete", when I check the domain in "Query HSTS/PKP domain", it still shows the should-be-deleted information as if I didn't ask it to delete that.

Comment: Currently it is no longer possible to disable it. I had to install version 78 of Chrome to re-use it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452249/1184296) from @IvanEfremov for a solution which works

Comment: This answer works perfectly in 2023

Answer (score 422):

I experienced the same problem in Chrome and I tried unsuccessfully to use [BigJump's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586593/453277).

I fixed my problem by forcing a hard refresh, as shown in this [blog](http://galaxyinternet.us/google-chrome-redirects-localhost-to-https-fix/) (originally from this [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/869739/372811)).

Ensure your address bar is using the http scheme and then go through these steps, possibly a couple of times:

1. Open the Developer Tools panel (CTRL+SHIFT+I)
2. Click and hold the reload icon / Right click the reload icon.
3. A menu will open.
4. Choose the 3rd option from this menu ("Empty Cache and Hard Reload")

Comment: You can also right-click on the refresh/reload icon to get to the _Hard Reload_ menu

Comment: I cannot get this solution to work.  The problem is that it does a hard reload on https://localhost:3000 (in my case).  Attempting to change the protocol before the reload but that doesn't work.

Comment: Worked for me by pressing "CTRL + SHIFT + R" for a hard reload.

Comment: On chromium, it is F12 and not CTRL+SHIFT+I

Comment: Also for me this worked, with a slight tweak: I am working on a couple of apps in Django, and one of them was applying a permanent redirect. Doing the hard reload on the old address cleared the cache, but the address was still old (and wrong). But at the second attempt, correcting the address in the address bar made the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 216):

NEW DEVELOPMENTS! (if you have Chrome 63+)

If your localhost domain is `.dev` then I don't think the previously accepted answer works. The reason why is because since Chrome 63, Chrome will force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS.

What this means is, `.dev` basically won't work at all anymore unless you have proper signed SSL certificate -- no more self signed certificates allowed! [Learn more at this blog post.](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

So to fix this issue now and to avoid this happening again in the future `.test` is one recommended domain because it is reserved by IETF for testing / dev purposes. You should also be able to use `.localhost` for local dev.

Comment: This was my problem.
If local with an Apache virtual host setup, you can try
# Add to your VH config:
 ServerAlias sitename.test
 ServerAlias www.sitename.test
# Add:
 sitename.test to /etc/hosts
# Restart Apache.
# Update links if needed

Comment: I changed all .dev domains to .app, still same issue. Any pointers on what the issue might be?

Comment: Hmm. You should try using .test or .localhost as suggested. I'm not sure if .app is another of the domains Chrome is force re-directing to HTTPS but as that's a real domain and it's another one owned by Google it's a risk either way and likely the problem.

Comment: `.localhost` didn't work for me either, but `.test` did. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff try using `.test`

Comment: project.test instead of opening project does google search, what can be the cause?

Comment: @KailashVele google thinks it's a search query. Just put a `/` at the end of it like `project.test/`. Google will cache it so you won't have to type that / again after that.

Comment: This is _EXTREMELY_ annoying. Surely there must be some way to not force us to change our development domain, right?

Comment: replacing `.dev` by `.test` worked for me too in Chrome 63

Comment: These counter-intuitive defaults are terrible. Why should one lose time debugging their dev environment setup, or just guessing what's going wrong, just to discover that everything is okay their side and it is Google Chrome that redirects .dev to HTTPS by default. Where is the logic. Why .dev and why not other TLD(s)?  Absolutely not intuitive.

Comment: @Meglio Because `.dev` actually exists as a new gTLD and it is owned by Google.

Answer (score 101):

Piggybacking off [Adiyat Mubarak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139466/5348487)

Could not hard refresh as it was just refreshing on https. Follows some of the same steps.

```
1. Open chrome developer tools (ctrl + shift + i)
2. Network Tab at the top
3. Click Disable cache checkbox at the top (right under network tab for me).
4. Refresh page (while the developer tools is still open)
```

Comment: I'm using a .local domain and this worked when the HSTS solution above did not.

Comment: when I did that the first time, it didn't work but I noticed an input on the same tap which is "Network" on the left that contains "domain:127.0.0.1 scheme:https", I just modify it to "domain:127.0.0.1 scheme:HTTP" by removing "s" char from http and has worked

Comment: This was the first solution that worked, since every other solution redirected back to the https domain.

Answer (score 50):

Go to

```
chrome://net-internals/#hsts
```

Enter localhost under Delete domain security policies and press the Delete button.

Now go to

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

tick the box Cached images and files and press click the button Clear data.

Answer (score 49):

I am facing the same problem but only in **Chrome Canary** and searching a solution I've found [this post](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

> one of the next versions of Chrome is going to force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPs via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.

```
{ "name": "dev", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
{ "name": "foo", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https" },
```

So, change your domains.

Comment: .test is a special reserved tld that should remain safe.

Comment: 09-12-2022: this solution doesn't work. I have tried all the solutions listed on this page. Nothing works.

Answer (score 26):

Open `Chrome Developer Tools` -> go to `Network` -> select `Disable Cache` -> reload

Comment: But this disable cache for all websites you have in a normal Chrome windows... that's not nice...
I was able, later, to clean the cache and enable the cache option again and still seems to work...

Comment: This is a clean and simple solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

I also have been struggling with this issue. Seems that [HSTS is intended for only domain names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#page-44). So if you are developing in local machine, it much easier to use IP address. So I switched from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 18):

Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header. [You can find more information about this here.](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

Comment: ^^ Ditto. It affected our `.app` domains in the last week as well. We're temporarily switching to `.test` although I don't think that's a long-term solution.

Answer (score 17):

from https://galaxyinternet.us/google-chrome-redirects-localhost-to-https-fix/

None of the option fixes worked for me, for fixing `https://localhost:3000`, this did.

click and hold `Reload` Button and select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`, this seems to only be an option on `localhost`

Comment: Latest Chrome updated so this solution will no longer work.

Comment: This should work on all domains if you have the developer toolbar open

Answer (score 13):

A lazy and fast solution for lazy people like me (working in Chrome 67).

Just launch another Chrome window in **Stealth Mode**, with the "Incognito Window" option (CTRL + SHIFT + N). No need to delete cache, no need to dive into deep Chrome settings, etc.

Comment: This works, but it makes my AJAX requests extremely slow because of provisional headers.

Answer (score 11):

How I solved this problem with chrome 79:

Just paste this url in you search input *chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost*

It helped me by using experimental features.

Answer (score 7):

I never figured out the root of the problem however I was able to fix this problem.
I deleted the Google Chrome app cache folder which solved the problem.

C:\Users[users]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome

Comment: I believe the issue is that Chrome stores when you visit a domain using HTTPS and then if you ever visit the same domain again it automatically switches to HTTPS. Its a pain in the arse as a developer because once you access any localhost site using HTTPS, suddenly all locahost sites are redirected to HTTPS.

Comment: @DaleBurrell You are not right. This is caused by HSTS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Answer (score 7):

This can be caused by a cached https redirect, and can be fixed by clearing the cache manually as in Adiyat Mubarak's answer.

But if you are visiting localhost you likely are a developer, in which case you will find a cache clearing chrome extension such as "classic cache killer" (see e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/classic%20cache%20killer?hl=en) useful in a variety of situations, and likely already have one installed.

So the quick fix is: Install a cache killer (if you don't have one already), turn it on, and reload the page.  Done!

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me. It started happening after a chrome update (Version 63.0.3239.84, linux) with a local URL. Would always redirect to https no matter what. Lost some hours and a lot of patience on this

What did worked after all was just changing the domain.

For what is worth, the domain was .app. Perhaps it got something to do? And just changed it to .test and chrome stopped redirecting it

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, none of the solution listed here helped me to resolve this issue.  I fixed this issue by using http://127.0.0.1 (ip address) instead of http://localhost.  A quick little hack to work with angular development with chrome browser.

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution to this is to edit your `/etc/hosts` file and establish one alias per project.

```
127.0.0.1   project1 project2 project3
```

These domainless names will never have the problem with HSTS unless you send the HSTS response mentioned by @bigjump and with the added benefit of maintaining your login session if you change back and forth between projects.

Answer (score 5):

Tried everything mentioned (browser preferences, hsts, etc.) but nothing worked for me.

I solved it by adding a trailing `.localhost` to the host aliases. In my case this file under windows: `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Like this:

```
127.0.0.1    myproject.localhost
127.0.0.1    dev.project.localhost
```

Comment: I'm supposed to avoid making comments like "thanks" but this was driving me crazy for hours and using `my-domain.localhost` was the only thing that worked. Ta!

Answer (score 3):

Go to

```
chrome://net-internals/#hsts
```

Enter the domain under Delete domain security policies and press the Delete button.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had my project path set as `/Users/me/dev/project_root/` and was running the `nodeJS`/`express` server from there.
Renaming my path to `/Users/me/project_root` (removing `dev` from the path to project) resolved the issue.

Most likely has to do with this new regulation:

> Chrome 63 (out since December 2017), will force all domains ending on .dev (and .foo) to be redirected to HTTPS via a preloaded HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.

You can find more information about this [here](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

Using:

- Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- nodeJS v9.2.0

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions worked for me. As a temporary work around, I go to:

http://127.0.0.1:3000/

(replace `3000` with desired port) And I can at least access my local host that way!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in Chrome and then to Advanced settings, under privacy and security section click Clear browsing data and then clear all data. I followed these steps and it worked for me. Hope it helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 63 forces .dev domains automatic to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS. 
Quick fix: just change the .dev domains to .localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, it's just a workaround.

1. Click on your visual studio project (top level) in the solution explorer and go to the properties window.
2. Change SSL Enabled to true. You will now see another port number as 'SSL URL' in the properties window.
3. Now, when you run your application (or view in browser), you have to manually change the port number to the SSL port number in the address bar.

Now it works fine as a SSL link

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be replicated in VS 2019 also. This is caused due to "Enable Javascript debugging from Visual Studio IDE". The VS attaches to Chrome and it is a possibility that due to security or reasons known to Google and Microsoft, it sometimes fails to attach and you have this issue. I am able to run http and https with localhost from ASP net core 3.1 app. So while debugging in VS, go to the run with arrow -> IIS express, just below "Web Browser(Chrome)" select "Script Debugging (Disabled)".

See article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugging-web-applications?view=vs-2019

Always fallback to Microsoft docs to get more clarity than googling an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked in Chrome 90. My app opened up a local webpack server on `localhost:3000` which automatically redirected to HTTPS, and I got `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

I clicked on the little info icon next to the URL, opened up the Site Settings from the menu dropdown. In the list, the `Insecure content` was set to `Block (default)`.

I changed this to `Allow`, and just reloaded the http version and it loaded fine.

Hope this will help people out.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any solution to work; but a redirect in my web.config allowed me to continue to work (localhost) until I find what is causing the issue.

This is essentially a rewrite rule that turns HTTPS to HTTP; it seems to have overwritten the previous rule that redirected HTTP to HTTPS.

It needs to be within your <system.webServer> </system.webServer> section in web.config

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using browser-sync on a Mac and the browser kept redirecting http://localhost:3000 to https://localhost:3000.

I am using Valet to serve local sites, and I had run `valet secure` on the local *.test domain to give it a SSL cert. Because I was proxying this HTTPS domain in browser-sync, the browser was loading localhost:3000 with HTTPS.

To fix it I had to:

1. run `valet unsecure` to remove the SSL cert
2. run `valet restart`
3. restart browser-sync
4. open localhost:3000 in the browser ([Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) in my case which is a Chromium browser)
5. Open Developer Tools
6. Tick "Disable Cache" on the Network tab
7. Refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this error message was sending me down a rabbit hole.

The problem for me was that the page I was trying to load on `http` was failing to return a response (due to a bug in my code that was crashing the server).

Chrome was automatically trying `https` automatically as a backup so, instead of seeing the actual error (page timed out), I was seeing the SSL error which was a red herring.

Fixing the underlying server crash & navigating back to `http://localhost:5000` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be working on a Wordpress site, and after trying everything on this page and still the http://127.0.0.1/wp-admin get redirected to https://127.0.0.1/wp-admin. Try this:

Go to wp-config.php and replace

define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');

define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');

to

define('WP_HOME','http://127.0.0.1');

define('WP_SITEURL','http://127.0.0.1');

Tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

For someone who had the same problem I solved by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE to delete just the entire browser cache. Now I can access my localhost website on HTTP protocol.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone running a Node.js express server on localhost like me, I have this piece of code that redirects http to https:

```
const server = express() 
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https') {
      res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
```

You have to make sure it doesn't redirect localhost:

```
const server = express() 
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https' && req.headers['host'].indexOf("localhost") == -1) {
      res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -2):

@Adiyat Mubarak answer did not work for me. When I attempted to clear the cache and hard-reload, the page still redirected to https.

My solution: In the upper right-hand corner of the url bar (just to the left of the favorites star icon) there is an icon with an "x" through it.  Right-click on that, and it will say something about "unsafe scripts", then there is an option to load them anyway. Do that.

Answer (score -2):

Another option would be to use something like https://github.com/rchampourlier/tunnelss

Sure it added another dependency / setup, but it also enables testing of https in dev, which could be nice.

I use RVM however to get tunnelss working I had to use `sudo gem install tunnelss` and `sudo tunnelss`

Answer (score -4):

That's the fastest solution today (17-3-2018):

Close all Chrome tabs / windows and run on your command line this: (or add it as a shortcode)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors
```