# Chrome Says "This webpage is not available" When I Run My MVC Project as http

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-chrome, iis, ssl

Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and IIS 8.5

I started an MVC 5 project and have been messing around with ssl. Everything worked great until I opened IIS and added a website that pointed to my project. Now, I can run the project with ssl enabled but NOT with it disabled. If I disable ssl, I get the following [Error Message in Chrome](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10923334_10204197637914052_1265579316577556408_n.jpg?oh=ee4c56580ef0ad461a3bfdd309ce5ba2&oe=55337208&__gda__=1429799517_afc17ed2b01915a63674c27e86bb34da).

I'm fairly certain my project is setup correctly in Visual Studio. "SSL Enabled" is `false` and the "Project Url" is `http://localhost:#####/` straight form the project's properties.

When this started happening, I figured it was IIS and so I deleted the Site from IIS. This obviously did not fix it. So I tried looking online but couldn't find anything helpful. The only other ounce of information is a [photo of the request being redirected](https://scontent-b-dfw.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/10933970_10204197637874051_8356513496959303404_n.jpg?oh=b1da18ff877315607d3fe29ff6468468&oe=553E1AD9) in Chrome's network window.

Keep in mind when I run locally with ssl, everything works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)