# Chrome redirects to https

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, redirect, http-redirect

Chrome has cached a 301 redirect from http:// example.com to https:// example.com and from http:// sub.example.com to https:// sub.example.com.

I've tried the following things:

1. Privacy settings-> Clear browsing data (from the beginning of time)
2. HTTPS/SSL-> Manage certificates -> Deleted all items (including certificates)
3. Checked that no bookmark is present.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532471/firefox-redirects-to-https) for Firefox but its solution doesn't work for Chrome. Does anybody have suggestions on what I can do about it? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but in case you or somebody else still has this problem, here is a solution that worked for me:

1) In the Chrome address bar type "chrome://net-internals/#hsts"

2) At the very bottom of a page is QUERY domain textbox - verify that localhost is known to the browser

3) If it is, DELETE the localhost domain using the textbox above

4) Your site should now work using plain old HTTP

From: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444479

*In your specific case, you should put example.com (not localhost) in step # 2 & 3 above*. You might have to restart Chrome afterwards.