# Firefox keeps redirecting to https

Tags: firefox, http-redirect

The answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532471/firefox-redirects-to-https) do not match my problem. I accidentally landed on http://sub.domain.org/ which [301 redirected me](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) to https://sub.domain.org/. Then I changed my server config so that it does not redirect me anymore, but Firefox keeps redirecting. The Firefox console log says:

```
GET http://sub.domain.org/            [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 0ms]
GET https://sub.domain.org/
```

So question is: how to make Firefox forget this "permanent redirection" specifically? I would prefer not delete my whole cache.

Comment: Have you tried to open the history and filter by *sub.domain.org* ? So you can erase only these entries.

Comment: Yes, already did it, does not work. Removing the cache works, but I would like to avoid it and target the redirection specifically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox redirects to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532471/firefox-redirects-to-https)

Comment: As written in the question, it does not match the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution, easy.

Open Firefox and in the address bar type this URL

> http://sub.domain.org/?fake_parameter_to_bypass_cache

This should force the browser to reload the web page from http://

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from the user interface, I find this solution.

1. Download the single executable [sqlite3](http://sqlite.org/download.html)
2. Close Firefox
3. Find the directory where firefox has created your user profile.
4. Find the places.sqlite file, it is a sqlite database.
5. Open the datatabase

> sqlite3 places.sqlite

and delete the specific records, for examples with

> DELETE FROM moz_places WHERE url LIKE '%sub.domain.org%';

Repeat for the other tables (moz_hosts, moz_historyvisits, etc...).

Hint: make a copy of the file before your deletions.

---

To know which tables to prune, search on the web for

> firefox forensics history

For example I found this [article](https://www.dataforensics.org/mozilla-firefox-forensics/)