# How do I stop local IIS from going to https

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I stop local IIS on my Win7 Pro machine from going to https from http?
MVC 5 project. I inherited this from another developer.

Every time I start the prj or hit the local iis page manually, it keeps forwarding to https.

Comment: have you checked the binding options of your site?

Comment: where? In iis? Yes, it is running as a vir-dir in my localhost under the main site which is only bound to 80. Which is ideal. I do NOT want SSL. I want it to stop going to https and stay on http... its redirecting on it's own.

Comment: can you check your web project's properties should include 'SSL Enabled' which should be set to false

Comment: I don't have the choice for 'SSL Enabled'. I'm on VS 2015, MVC 5, 4.5.2 framework. I have ReSharper if that makes a diff...

Comment: check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)

Comment: Thanks but yea, tried that already, no go... weird

Comment: does it actually resolve to anything or does it say the page is not available?

Comment: Check if your controllers don't have a `[RequireHttps]` attribute

Comment: bingo, the dev put require https on the home controller, that's why it kept doing that. I hadn't checked yet, just got the project. Thanks. Write it as an answer and I'll mark it.