# ASP.NET WebForms localhost redirecting to https with port change

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, localhost

I have an ASP.NET WebForms project where I'm using Visual Studio Development Server with Auto-Assign Port enabled. When I try to debug the application, it starts off with http://localhost:1211 and then automatically redirects to https://localhost:0 - which gives me an error that the site can't be reached.
I've already tried the different solutions mentioned here : [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)
but I'm unable to get it to work.
This problem started since I got the latest version of the project from TFS. The previous version runs fine. Am I missing anything ?