# Firefox redirects localhost to HTTPS

Tags: firefox, https

There is a similar question about the same issue on Chrome, with an answer that solves it in Chrome.

When I try to go to `http://localhost:8000/`, Firefox redirects me to `https://localhost/` . Why? If I open an incognito window, this doesn't happen. I can't continue developing until I solve this. Please help.

Comment: Sadly, it appears a Private/incognito window no longer works around this issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So, here is my experience. I had the same issue.

At first : try in private mode. If you dont have the problem, do this :

When you open a new tab, you have to go to the Firefox configuration ("about:config") you check "I'll be careful I promise". Then in the search field you type autofill, you have to set browser.urlbar.autofill to false and if it still doesn't work you can delete the history, it should fix it. It worked for me.

I think the problem comes from the fact that I opened once localhost in https so the browser wants to do it every time.

Comment: None of those worked for me (I have the problem not with localhost/ but with a domain, that I redirected to localhost in my /etc/hosts/ file) It seems to be a hsts problem, cause I could solve it in Chrome like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586593/1069083

Comment: It worked for me after I set it to false and deleted the history also. My problem was the redirect from localhost:8080/ to localhost:8080/auth/.

Answer (score 54):

This happened to me after I worked on a site that used https and then tried switching back to one that does not.

Unfortunately, the accepted answer did not work for me. What I needed to do was:

1. Open the Firefox History (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>)
2. Find the page (`127.0.0.1:3000`, in my case)
3. Right-click it and choose the last option: "Forget About This Site"

If you use `localhost` - with our without port - to access your page, then you will notice that `localhost` does not show up in your history. This makes it impossible to access the "Forget About This Site" option.

Fear not! You can work around that issue.

1. Visit your site using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. So, for example, `localhost:3000` becomes `127.0.0.1:3000`.
2. Now open the Firefox History (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>)
3. Find the page (`127.0.0.1`), right-click, and "Forget About This Site"
4. Now, access `localhost` and you will find that it works again. This is because forgetting about `127.0.0.1` cleared data for both `127.0.0.1` as well as for `localhost`.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer first, but only yours actually fixed the problem for me. Cheers.

Comment: this is the solution that works for me on Mac OS Big Sur 11.4

Comment: 127.0.0.1 doesn't even show up in history for me

Comment: only this answer allowed me to access again a site with http. rightclick and choose "forget complete webseite"

Answer (score 15):

I'm running MAMP on OSX with default ports (`http://localhost`) and what worked for me was changing this preference to false on `about:config`:

```
browser.fixup.fallback-to-https
```

I tried clearing History, Site Preferences, changing `browser.urlbar.autofill` and `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist`, disabling all extensions, but none of these worked.

Comment: Worked for me too, on 78.8, on CentOS 8

Comment: Worked for me with Ventura 13.0.1 and FF108.

Answer (score 7):

In their last update, Chrome and Firefox browsers now redirect all domains with the pattern *.dev and *.foo to https.  I found a solution for Firefox but, haven't yet found a solution for Chrome.

for Firefox

```
Visit the address about:config
Search for the parameter network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist and change it's value to false
```

Since this question refers to a localhost, alternative solutions involve:

- Change your URLs and use new domains .
- Modify the hosts file, If you point on IP addresses or virtual hosts, you can modify your hosts file to use local domains
- Or, Use SSL, you can choose to activate SSL
  on your web server.

Source: https://tutoref.com/how-to-prevent-firefox-and-chrome-from-forcing-dev-and-foo-domains-to-use-https/

Comment: I tried this, but it had no effect. it still redirects my test-domain foo.example.com to https://foo.example.com – maybe because the domain really exists, and I just redirected it to localhost in my hosts file?

Comment: This fixed my issue. I was using .home domain for my self-hosted servers ,so it isn't limited to only the .dev domain.

Comment: This is the only thing worked for me - and the context was I added `dev` to my /etc/hosts to resolve to 127.0.0.1 because I want to use a host header with nginx instead of a raw IP.

Comment: Did not work for me (Firefox 120)

Answer (score 6):

The solution that worked for me:

1. Go to about:config
2. Look for `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist` and set it to "false"
3. Enjoy

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me!  Thanks, Reza!

Comment: This one worked for me on 87.0 (64-bit) on Arch Linux. Thank you Reza Shek! =)

Comment: This is the only thing worked for me - and the context was I added `dev` to my /etc/hosts to resolve to 127.0.0.1 because I want to use a host header with nginx instead of a raw IP.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a [Pluto.jl](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl) instance, the only workaround so far was to launch in a private window:

```sh
firefox -new-instance -P Pluto --private-window http://localhost:1237
```

[Finns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408398/3565696) fixed it once, but subsequent calls timed out.

Comments left in a [relevant bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1679249#c4).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was fixed by restarting the Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What ended up working for me was toggling Enhanced Tracking Protection to OFF via the shield icon in the address bar. I did this for both localhost and the site that it was redirecting to. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the top answer and deleting individual history didn't do the trick for me. I tried deleting history from `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and `0.0.0.0`, but still saw the issue. When I cleared *all* of my history, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
[image]

I pressed on the "Clear cookies and site data..." and then remove on the pop-up.

Cheers!