# How to permanently exclude localhost from HSTS list in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, hsts

This is a followup question to [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https).

Does anyone know, how to permanently exclude `localhost` from HSTS list in Google Chrome?

Or, any other elegant solution that wouldn't require developer to visit `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and delete `localhost` every time when switching from working on an HTTPS project to a different project on HTTP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:**

> You can install a proper SSL certificate for those domains if you want to for free, so you won't need to mess around with HSTS. Take a look [here](https://letsencrypt.org).

---

You may edit your system's hosts file:

- On Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- On Linux: `/ets/hosts`

In there you can define a different domain for each project:

```
 127.0.0.1    project1.local
 127.0.0.1    project2.local
 127.0.0.1    projectN.local
```

> Note: I'm using *.local domains (you can use virtually anything) because you have already set localhost to redirect to https, and such we have to use a different domain. Although I strongly recommend you to install a real SSL certificate and reset to default any modifications you have made on HSTS.

Once saved, when you navigate to those domain in any browser it will load from `127.0.0.1` (localhost). If you use apache/nginx as server you optionally can define VirtualHosts for each domain also so you don't need to change your httpd folder every time you switch projects.

Then of course you will have to re-issue any certificate that you may have for those projects for the new domains, but those would be unique for each project. And on Chrome you would not need to be messing net-internals more than once for each domain for the projects which you don't have a certificate (and 0 times for those with certificate).

Comment: Good one, however this only works if you omit the `.localhost` part. (If I keep it there, it still redirects to https.) Could you please edit your answer?

Comment: Edited, also added an alternative to HSTS.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: Chrome still switches to https and port 8443.

Comment: Have you cleared the HSTS for the domain? This answer provides an alternative to use several projects in the localhost it will not work if you use more than one project per domain with different security requirements.

Comment: Has anyone tried the *.local since Chrome 71?  I've been using the *.local trick for several months, but after upgrade to Chrome 71 it's no longer working for me.

Comment: Please note that `project1.dev`, `local.dev` and other `*.dev` are not good choices simply because Chromium started enforcing HSTS soon after Google bought .dev as gTLD.

Answer (score 81):

You can follow the solution [here](http://galaxyinternet.us/google-chrome-redirects-localhost-to-https-fix/).

When Google Chrome keeps redirecting your localhost Url from `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`, do the following:

1. Open the Developer Tools panel (CTRL+SHIFT+I)
2. Click and hold the reload icon
3. A menu will open
4. Choose the 3rd option from this menu (“Empty Cache and Hard Reload”)

Comment: Cool! Too bad these options don't pop out without Developer Tools. I'm still looking for a more "permanent" solution, but this definitely helps! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, here on Chrome `79.0.3945.117` on windows, and this solution didn't work. I continued to get the 307 redirect. I still had to visit `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and delete it.

Comment: Step 1.5 is switch back to the tab from which you're loading the localhost page/path.

Comment: I had a redirect setup in my `/etc/hosts` file for `localhost.[some-domain].com` and `[some-domain].com` had an entry in `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`.  

In this case attempt to delete the `localhost.[some-domain].com` and if that doesn't work try deleting `[some-domain].com` from hsts.

Comment: i found this working to also clear some pre-cached HSTS value (or whatever it was) so that i could finally always end up in the http:// mode for a page view - instead of getting permanent redirection to https:// mode for the same page address.

Answer (score 13):

Chrome 78 supports a policy called [HSTSPolicyBypassList](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=HSTSPolicyBypassList). You can list "localhost" as a domain to bypass HSTS.
To configure Chrome policy on Linux, just create a file at /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/policies.json with the following content:

```
{
    "HSTSPolicyBypassList": [
        "localhost"
        ]
}
```

You can see the policies loaded by Chrome, typing chrome://policy/ at address bar.

Comment: For Brave browser I had to create this file at: `/etc/brave/policies/managed/policies.json`

Answer (score 12):

### Not a permanent fix (security issue can be involved)

I found a "fix". Something interesting, but cannot be a permanent fix because it can cause multiple security issues.

Here's what I did:

1. Open Google Chrome
2. In the Search Bar type `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`
3. Enabled `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.`

If you reload your application, the warning should be gone.

PS I did that because I needed to recreate a certification but didn't have the time. That's why I did that. I'll turn off this when my certification will work locally.

Answer (score 4):

I got sick of deleting `localhost` from chrome://net-internals/#hsts , so I learned how to create a profile for macOS that sets two Chrome policies:
`HSTSPolicyBypassList` + `CertificateTransparencyEnforcementDisabledForURLs`

Here is a repo with the installable profile for macOS that configures the policy, along with notes on why `defaults write com.google.Chrome HSTSPolicyBypassList -string "localhost"` doesn't work. https://github.com/ip2k/I-Dont-Care-About-HSTS-For-Localhost

Additionally, chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost and https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Security/#method-setIgnoreCertificateErrors might be interesting for people working with this frequently or in headless environments. I've added links in the aforementioned repo to anything relevant I could find about this as well. PRs welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For Brave Windows users, you need to add it like this via Registry Editor, under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\BraveSoftware\Brave\HSTSPolicyBypassList`, with key `100` and value `localhost`:
[image: Registry Editor screenshot]

And you can verify that it's working under brave://policy.
[image: An example of working brave setup]