# django site ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR after https setting

Tags: django, https, server, django-deployment

So I am trying to deploy my site and basically tried

```
python manage.py check --deploy
```

and followed what ever it told me:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
?: (security.W006) Your SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'x-content-type-options: nosniff' header. You should consider enabling this header to prevent the browser from identifying content types incorrectly.
?: (security.W007) Your SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block' header. You should consider enabling this header to activate the browser's XSS filtering and help prevent XSS attacks.
?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SSL connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.
?: (security.W012) SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is not set to True. Using a secure-only session cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to hijack user sessions.
?: (security.W016) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to True. Using a secure-only CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to steal the CSRF token.
?: (security.W017) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY to True. Using an HttpOnly CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for cross-site scripting attacks to steal the CSRF token.
?: (security.W018) You should not have DEBUG set to True in deployment.
?: (security.W019) You have 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE, but X_FRAME_OPTIONS is not set to 'DENY'. The default is 'SAMEORIGIN', but unless there is a good reason for your site to serve other parts of itself in a frame, you should change it to 'DENY'.
?: (security.W020) ALLOWED_HOSTS must not be empty in deployment.
```

Basically setting all those to True in settings.py and set Debug mode to False, and put SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 300

However, I forgot to set up my site on a server before doing this and now when I tried to access it, it gives me this error in browser:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8001. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

and those in cmd:

```
[14/Sep/2016 17:40:46] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00|\x01\x00\x00x\x03\x02\xd3\xb8S<\t¿°\xfd½U»ïä\x98\x99h\xb9¥±T~\x129\x05á\xc0V\t\x9a\xe3\x82E\x00\x00\x10\xc0\t\xc0\x13\xc0')
[14/Sep/2016 17:40:46] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Okay so it clearly tell me the problem: I am not supporting HTTPs but the setting is set to support it. But the weird thing is even after I delete all those settings, the site stays this way and I just can't even access it in development with DEBUG = True.

I even tried to use git to revert to the version before I did this, and it doesn't help. The same error remains. Now I am really worried that maybe I just destroyed it? Please somebody help me

Comment: On Chrome, this solved the problem for me: https://superuser.com/a/881431/892913

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried a different browser to access your (dev) website? Maybe its because of the value you gave on the setting [`SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-seconds). If this is too high (say 31536000 == 1 year) the browser will keep hitting the `https` version of your site.

However, you can clear the browser's HSTS setting. Maybe [this](https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/clear-hsts-browser/) can help.

For a better understanding of HSTS (if this is the issue) read [this](https://www.chosenplaintext.ca/articles/why-hsts.html) article.

Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: I found this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968510/how-to-permanently-exclude-localhost-from-hsts-list-in-google-chrome) useful for resetting localhost HSTS in Google Chrome.