# Why does Django refuses http connection on a specific route, but on other routes http works properly?

Tags: python, django, http, https, hsts

I have a Django project. Its routes are:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))
]
```

When I was preparing the project for production, I set `SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS` to 3600 seconds. Right after this, I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Qrn.png). I tried to set this variable to 1 second, but It didn't help. Also, I tried to remove this variable, but my app still doesn't work. I also noticed, that when I hit the `https://localhost:8000/projects/` route, Django automatically sets HTTP to HTTPS and even when I change HTTPS to HTTP manually, It's still not going to work. However, it works if I change my route to something different, like `http://localhost:8000/works/`. I already tried to clear cache in google chrome, head to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and delete `localhost` from security policies. And I even updated my `SECRET_KEY`. Now I think, the only way to solve this issue is to recreate the project, but I can't do this, because all the data will be deleted. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500163/django-site-err-ssl-protocol-error-after-https-setting

Comment: Had you set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` too?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, it's set to `False`, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @V.D. yeah I already tried it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Hey! Did you solve it? If yes, how? I have same problem right now and I can't handle it. Can you help me pls? :'(

I did 
```SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True```
and I still getting error like ```ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR```