# How to handle http requests which are getting redirected as https using my nodejs-express app?

Tags: node.js, https, request, hsts, node-https

I am injecting some script tags in a website, with source such as `http:localhost:3000/css/my-page-css.css` . While its working on almost all sites, there's this particular website that is somehow sending all my `http` requests as `https`. How do I handle such a case?

I have configured an https server also on my nodejs app which listens to port `8443` and http listens to `3000`. But, when I inject my script tags, they have src URLS which point to port `3000`. So even if I have an https configured on my nodejs app, it won't work since it would be listening to a different port.

Comment: I would imagine you are using HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) or a domain that enforces HSTS (e.g. a domain ending .app).

Comment: This site is using it `https://thenameshirts.com/products/aaberg-an-endless-legend-1` . My nodejs is just acting as a proxy server and adding some scripts before sending the response. So how do I bypass that? @BarryPollard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)

Using [the securityheader.com website on your URL](https://securityheaders.com/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fthenameshirts.com&hide=on&followRedirects=on), or Chrome Developer tools we see the following HTTP Header is sent back by your site:

```
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=7889238
```

This HTTP Header will be configured in your webserver and is a way of your webserver telling the browser "For the next 7889238 seconds only use HTTPS on this domain. If someone tries to use HTTP (either by typing or by clicking on a link) then automatically switch HTTP to HTTPS before you send it on to the server."

This is a security feature as currently the default (if a scheme is not explicitly given) is HTTP. This allows website owners to switch the default and, even strong that that, prevents it being able to be switched back.

HSTS is set at a domain level and it is not possible to have it on for one port (e.g. 443) but not for another (e.g. 3000) - it's either on for that domain or off.

If you really want to use HTTP then you need to remove this header and remove the remembered value of this header from your browser. While chrome allows you to do this by typing `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` in the URL and using the delete option, the easiest way to do this is to change the max age from 7889238 to 0, and then load the website again. And then remove the header completely.

This can be especially annoying for sites like localhost where you proxy requests and inadvertently set it for that dummy host name. You should see if your node proxy server allows you to strip off that HTTP header. [Some might say it would be better if browser makers ignored HSTS for localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968510/how-to-permanently-exclude-localhost-from-hsts-list-in-google-chrome), however I think it would be better if developers just stopped fighting HTTPS and used that even for development environments using a self-signed certificate that is added to your local trust store. This was you can avoid problems like mixed content, and also use features that are HTTPS only (including Brotli, HTTP/2, Geo Location...etc.) while developing (though some browsers like Chrome still allow these on http://localhost).

Alternatively [set up a local DNS alias for each of your dev sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968510/how-to-permanently-exclude-localhost-from-hsts-list-in-google-chrome#39671202) and use that with or without HTTPS as appropriate for the site in question.