# How can I stop the Azure DocumentDB Emulator from redirecting localhost to HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, http, azure, azure-cosmosdb, hsts

Whenever I start it, it sends an [HSTS header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586593/28901) which means every request now redirects from `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`.

This is a PITA when developing locally with node.js.

Is there a way to stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been fixed in recent builds. Try re-installing the latest build?

Comment: I have downloaded and reinstalled the emulator just now, v 1.11.72.11. localhost is still redirecting to https for every request. I suspect that whatever system configuration change made by my previous installation is still in effect, and has not been reset by the new installer. Is there a way to verify this/correct it?