# HTTP parse error, malformed request - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I see the following error in Terminal when attempting to run a Ruby on Rails app.

```
HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
2017-03-12 13:10:02 -0400: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"puma 3.4.0 Owl Bowl Brawl", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2"}
```

The browser error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection. localhost sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*
```

I have tried the following

- Clearing browser cache and restarting
- Reverting back to an old commit in GIT that was working at the time
- Restarting terminal
- Running a different rails app that was functional

Comment: First of all, delete all chache of chrome. It works well for me.

Answer (score 40):

Here are some possible solutions.

1. Make sure you are connecting through http://localhost:3000 and not https://localhost:3000.
2. If the browser redirects to HTTPS and it's Google Chrome, try this solution that addresses an HSTS problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586593
3. Make sure you do not have the production environment (if that's what you're serving) forcing HTTPS. If that's the problem, comment this out or change `true` to `false`:

   *config/environments/production.rb*

   ```
   # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
   config.force_ssl = true
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this shout, stupid me was using https instead of http

Comment: Took me a minute to realize I was accessing `https` instead of `http`, thanks to Chrome's stupid protocol hiding.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting through http://localhost:3000 and not https://localhost:3000, solved it for me.

Comment: @NemyaNation Thanks for your comment I was being stupid as well , used https for localhost 

Answer (score 7):

For those reading this in the future, consider the following:

1. Did you change your server in your Gemfile. e.g. from Puma to Thin?
2. Have you set up an SSL certificate?
3. Are you starting your webserver with SSL certificate flags?
4. Is SSL turned on in your development/production environment - and what environment are you invoking?

If you are ok with turning off SSL in your development environment you can do so by going to:

`config/environments/development.rb` and configuring:

`config.force_ssl = false`

Here is some code that works for me, using puma, that invokes SSL certification (locally). I have created my certificates and have dumped it in the relevant location:

`rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=./.ssl/localhost.key&cert=./.ssl/localhost.crt'`

When I want to run it in a production environment from my PC I using the following:

`rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=./.ssl/localhost.key&cert=./.ssl/localhost.crt' -e production`

HTH

Answer (score 6):

seems like you are trying to run HTTPS on your local. You need to have a TLS toolkit (like openSSL) installed on your local. 
[OPENSSL for example](https://www.openssl.org/).

after you made sure of that, and if still not working, maybe you can find you're answer in the next Github issue. Seems like a bug with Puma gem. 
[GITHUB ISSUE TALK](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/27)

Answer (score 2):

Faced this error as well,
If the above solutions don't work, do a quick check to see if you have this meta tag in your application.html.erb

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

This will force Google Chrome to redirect localhost to HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Access the app using a different browser, or if you are in Chrome access it in Incognito mode. After this the error did not show in any browser again. Remember to remove the `config.force_ssl` or set it to `false` in the `development.rb` file first.

Encountered this today after adding and then removing the `config.force_ssl = true` config in our Rails 6 app's `development.rb` file. Tried to access the app in localhost, in a Chrome browser, and the same error showed. Restared rails server several times, to no avail.

The accessing it in different browser, where the force ssl version of the app client was never opened, worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my  case it was silly mistake I started server on http and my url was pointing to https.
I hope it would save someone's time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting Content-Security-Policy in your application via action_dispatch.default_headers:

```
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers = ({
      'Content-Security-Policy' => "default-src 'self' https:;\
        font-src 'self' https: data:;\
        img-src 'self' https: data: blob:;\
        object-src 'self';\
        script-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';\
        style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';\
        upgrade-insecure-requests;\
        frame-ancestors *"
    })
```

Make sure to override that setting in your **development** environment to add http: options to these. Like so:

```
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers = ({
    'Content-Security-Policy' => "default-src 'self' http: https:;\
      font-src 'self' http: https: data:;\
      img-src 'self' http: https: data: blob:;\
      object-src 'self';\
      script-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';\
      style-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline';\
      frame-ancestors *"
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after running `RAILS_ENV=production rails server`.

Localhost should still work as expected in incognito or in a browser other than chrome.

#### 3 steps that solved it

1. Open the https://localhost:3000 (the http**s** version) in incognito
2. Open dev tools (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> on mac)
3. Hard refresh the page. Do this by either <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> or by holding shift and clicking the refresh button.
4. Now visit http://localhost:3000 (http version) and it should load as it normally would

This info is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33139466/5783745).

#### Notes

Once in the past I used a debugger in production and somehow got the same error. Here's what seemed to solve:

1. Put this in your address bar and hit enter:

```
chrome://settings/content/all?search=cookies
```

2. Look for the cookie(s) for the production website and delete them.
3. Visit localhost and see if works now
4. You have also have to close and reopen chrome.