# http://localhost:port always redirecting to https://localhost

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, localhost, iis-express

I'm building a simple website in vs2015.   I have IIS express selected as the hosting environment.   I have tried multiple new projects and seem to be going around in circles, having installed and uninstalled iis-express 10 multiple times, and added and removed windows feature of iis also.  When I launch a web project from vs2015, it used to open (without issue) a http://localhost:port (e.g. http://localhost:51898), but now continually redirects to https://localhost.

Any idea why?

Comment: In your solution folder you will find .vs folder. Try deleting it and rerunning application. You may have some redirection config in applicationhost.config file present in config folder inside .VS folder.

Comment: Try this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825407/microsoft-edge-redirects-http-localhost-to-https-localhost It solves the same issue.

Comment: Try this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825407/microsoft-edge-redirects-http-localhost-to-https-localhost
it solves the same issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

It is not about Visual Studio, it is about Chrome.
This solution worked for me: [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https/28586593#28586593)

Comment: the problem not in https but in lack of port. IIS can provide certificate for localhost, so https can not be a problem

Answer (score 2):

> the redirect will only happen with explict configuration and IIS or
>   asp.net will not automatically redirect .

- check following config files and loo for any redirect settings

  - ApplicationHost.Config,All web.config files  (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config)
    search for **httpRedirect**

e.g.  `<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://localhost" />`

- check for urlrewrite configurations. a typical rule will be like this .so you can search for **Redirect**

  ```
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.maindomain.com/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
  ```

  - If you do not find these settings anywhere in your configuration,your application code is doing this.Check your code

Comment: In my case, it was Release config, I was thinking I started my app in Debug, which does not have redirect

Answer (score 1):

In my situation it was caused by this piece of code:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

Anyway double check you startup.cs file. Maybe configurations there are part of a problem

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was a configuration i did on IIS for all my sites to load via https. The rewrite rule matched localhost as well and hence it redirects to https. I rewrote the redirect rule and it was ok.