# Microsoft Edge redirects http://localhost to https://localhost

Tags: http, redirect, https, localhost, microsoft-edge

I am encountering an issue where I am not able to open my localhost web apps because Microsoft Edge is redirecting the URL `http://localhost:3000` to `https://localhost:3000`. Due to this I get the error

> The connection for this site is not secure. localhost sent an invalid response.

Why is this happening and what is the fix to it?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I got a solution from this [article](https://medium.com/@hmheng/exclude-localhost-from-chrome-chromium-browsers-forced-https-redirection-642c8befa9b)

Following are the steps for Microsoft edge -

- Go to Edge browser and type following statement in
  address bar.

  `edge://net-internals/#hsts`
- Scroll all the way down to the section below and enter “localhost”, then click “Delete”.
  [image]