# "Unsafe Website" error in SAML2 redirect from SP to IdP. Only in MS Edge

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, saml-2.0, adfs

We're getting an "Unsafe Website" error from MS Edge when our SSO Service Provider (SP) redirects to our customer Identity Provider (IdP).  This only happens in Edge and only for that customer.  It's a multitenant environment and it works in Edge for all the other IdPs.  In other browsers, it works fine for this customer (and all the others).  Another odd thing is that it's not clear which site is considered unsafe.  In the page text, it displays the URL of the SP.  In the navigation bar, it displays the URL of the IdP.

[image]
[image]

Finally, if I watch the network tab, I can see that the redirect response from our SP is processed by the browser, which follows the URL in the location header and receives a 200 from ADFS.

[image]

I've tried reporting the site as safe numerous times, but have gotten no response from Microsoft, nor do I expect one at this point.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  Are there any new cookie restrictions or anything like that that may be affecting Edge and not other browsers?

Comment: It might be the customer's IdP not safe because only that one IdP is marked unsafe. The site is blocked by Microsoft Defender SmartScreen in Edge. Is there any SmartScreen related group policy set on that machine? You can try to use group policy [SmartScreenAllowListDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#smartscreenallowlistdomains) to list the site as trusted domain in Microsoft Defender SmartScreen to see if it can fix the issue.

Comment: That is possible, but the customer reports not having this problem with their IdP in Edge with any other SPs.  Also, I'm not positive that it's the IdP that SmartScreen is blocking because in some places SmartScreen references our SPs domain, but in other places, it references the domain of our customer's IdP (see above).  If anyone knows how to tell for sure, which site is actually flagged that would be really helpful.

Comment: I think group policy **SmartScreenAllowListDomains** can help to decide which one is actually flagged. You can first list customer's IdP to test, then remove customer's IdP and list your SPs domain to test. In which situation it works, that's what actually flagged.

Answer (score 0):

•   Also, the Edge browser employs Microsoft Defender SmartScreen to help identify potentially malicious websites. If a particular website has been reported as dangerous by other Microsoft Edge users, it can be identified as dangerous or unsafe by the browser. Thus, you can also try turning off the Microsoft SmartScreen from ‘Settings  Update & Security --> Windows Security --> App and browser control --> Reputation-based protection settings --> Smartscreen for Microsoft Edge --> Turn Off’ and then try reaching out to the adfs login page during authentication once again on MS Edge.

•   Please check domain security policy setting in Microsoft Edge for the ADFS server’s domain and the Service provider’s domain also. Go to Edge browser and type ‘edge://net-internals/#hsts’ and hit enter, then scroll down to the ‘Delete Domain Security Policies’ section and enter the domain name of the ADFS Server first and hit delete, then enter the domain name of the Service Provider and hit delete. Then check once again, the website should not report the error again.

Please check the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-neededge#disable-redirection-to-microsoft-edge

[Microsoft Edge redirects http://localhost to https://localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825407/microsoft-edge-redirects-http-localhost-to-https-localhost)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The second bullet point didn't seem to have any effect.  The first bullet point worked, but I can't expect my customer's users to disable Windows Defender SmartScreen.  We need a solution that can be implemented on the server side.

Comment: You can try adding the ADFS site where the user is redirected for authentication to the customer's central group policy in Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Security page so that it is reflected to all the browsers in the network and the issue will be resolved. Please refer this link for configuration of group policy :- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0baa6428-bf48-4e8a-82e1-b961918090d9/how-to-add-trusted-sites-to-group-policy?forum=winserverGP