# MS:Edge redirects http to https even with edge://flags/#edge-automatic-https disabled

Tags: microsoft-edge

Problems with Edge & https

We've a legacy web app that requires users to switch between https & http when accessing certain functionality. A huge design flaw from years ago that was never addressed and we just have to "live with it".

Users can only access the web app via vpn to a rdp server where the user starts the browser.

Till now users have been using IE11 and can happily switch back & forth between http & https

We now need to switch to Edge due to the imminent withdrawal of IE and have an issue whereby entering http://testsite.com will automatically redirect to https://testsite.com

We've found and set edge://flags/#edge-automatic-https to disabled.

If the browser cache is emptied and the user enters http://testsite.com that works great.
If the user subsequently enters https://testsite.com that works great also
However if they try to go back to http://testsite.com then it redirects to https://testsite.com - not so great

Have also switched off under "Privacy, search, and services" / "Address bar and search"

"Show me search and site suggestions using my typed characters"
and also
"Show me suggestions from history, favourites and other data on this device using my typed characters"

Any other suggestions ?

Microsoft Edge
Version 101.0.1210.53 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: Exists the same behaviour in Chrome browser?

Comment: Yes - same behavious exists in Chrome 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit) although I can't find an equivalent to #edge-automatic-https in Chrome

Comment: The edge browser is a custom modification from chrome browser. Either Google has removed the functionality in main code to take care on this (hidden) option or it is a general bug in Chrome code.

Comment: I tried to disable [relevant group policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#automatichttpsdefault) but this issue occurs as well, so I think it might be by design. You can send your feedback to related team on this issue, just press `Shift + Alt + I ` in Edge to edit your suggestion and send it.

Comment: Version 111.0.1661.44 (Official build) (64-bit) of Edge still has this badly implemented thing... sigh...

Answer (score 2):

Only thing that worked for me from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825407/microsoft-edge-redirects-http-localhost-to-https-localhost):

I got a solution from this [article](https://medium.com/@hmheng/exclude-localhost-from-chrome-chromium-browsers-forced-https-redirection-642c8befa9b)

Following are the steps for Microsoft edge -

- Go to Edge browser and type following statement in
  address bar.

  `edge://net-internals/#hsts`
- Scroll all the way down to the section below and enter “localhost”, then click “Delete”.
  [image]

Comment: the same exact issue is resolved the same way in Chrome: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`