# php localhost automatically redirects to https

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed xampp and when I type localhost into browser it automatically loads the dashboard page with https

```
https://localhost/dashboard/
```

When I place the project inside htdocs and run it through localhost/project, it automatically redirects to

```
https://localhost/project
```

How to prevent this behavior

Comment: Which browser are  you using? Chrome?

Comment: Yes. I am using chrome

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file which is set to redirect automatically?  Is there an xampp configuration setting which tries to force SSL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https  take a look at this one

Comment: I don't know that there's enough info to answer this. Maybe it's Apache doing it. Maybe your PHP script is doing it. Maybe there's a JS script doing it.

Comment: check your .htaccess file