# localhost MAMP with the shared database: Error - "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: database, localhost, mamp, symlink

I have a copy of MAMP installed on my iMac and on my MacBook Air and they share the same copy of a database through the Dropbox. And all worked fine just until now.

I think I got into my MAMP on one of my computers without waiting for the core files to be synchronized and maybe that causes conflict.

Now if I go to the **localhost** page I get

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

And if I go to any of my dev domains, for example, `example.dev` I get this

```
This site can’t be reached
example.dev refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Hope that someone who is more experienced in this field could tell me what may have happened and what do I need to tweak to restore it back.

Thankful in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was much easier than I was thinking about. The whole point is that Chrome doesn't support dev extensions since the version of Chrome 63 (out since December 2017) that's why this problem occurs.
Found the answers in these threads:

[Stack Overflow Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733988/localhost-refused-to-connect-mamp-pro) 
[Chrome 63 forces .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) by Mattias Geniar 
[Don't Use .dev For Development](https://iyware.com/dont-use-dev-for-development/) by Danny Wahl