# Chrome - Delete domain security policies is not Working for .app

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https, hsts

im trying to delete domain security policy in Google Chrome following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https) one.

But when i click to delete and clear data browser it not work.

my domain is: http://localhost.domain-test.app:57471 and i using Windows.

im following exacly instructions:

1. go to **chrome://net-internals/#hsts**
2. put localhost.domain-test.app in **Delete domain security policies**, click **Delete** Button. (put with port 57471 like example?)
3. go to settings -> advance settings -> clear data

Then, when i put my domain in chrome browser it force redirect to https. But im developing in localhost, i can't use https.

When i use Internet Explorer this problem not happen.

Thanks for all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .app top level domain is preloaded for HSTS in the Chrome source code so cannot be “reset”.

See this blog post for more information: https://www.blog.google/technology/developers/introducing-app-more-secure-home-apps-web/ and also here: https://get.app