# web connections redirected to https://localhost

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, https

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 & Chrome Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit). When I try to access some sites on the internet (quick examples are github.com and guru.com) it turns out that I get redirected to https://localhost
I have searched for a solution online without success, can anyone please help? Any suggestion towards the solution of this issue will be greatly appreciated. Trying lynx and links give the same results.

Comment: Checkout the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https

Comment: I fail to get how this relates to developing software, and believe @AdhershMNair link/duplicated should really be at poweruser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)

Comment: This Q is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please read [help] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.