# http://localhost:8080 redirects to https://localhost:8080 in catalina and chrome81

Tags: google-chrome, macos-catalina, hsts

Developing on macOS 10.15.4 and chrome 81.
If you access `https://localhost:9080` and then `http://localhost:8080` with two applications, `http://localhost:8080` and `https://localhost:9080` running, Redirect to `https://localhost:8080`.
Even if I delete `localhost` at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and also delete `cache`, I get the same problem when I access `https://localhost:9080`. 
I am looking for a radical solution to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)

Answer (score 2):

In other browsers it redirects as well. There are many working around that settings change in time, depends on browsers & other tools. The easiest is just to use the IP address

```
127.0.0.1
```

instead of 'localhost'. In your case:

```
127.0.0.1:8080
```