# Clean .net 5 api project always redirecting to https in iis

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I have a clean .net 5 api project that will always redirect(307) to https for some reason when accessing the site thew iis 10. The site didn't have https enabled when it was created. The only thing special about the setup is that the site in iis uses a custom domain (api.projectname.dev) defined in the host file that points to 127.0.0.1. The the api doesn't redirect if I run it using iis express using visual studio. And the default iis site doesn't redirect to https. Does anyone know what might be the cause of this?

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "project.Api", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "project.Api v1"));
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net5.0\project.Api.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does your startup contains `app.UseHsts();`?

Comment: Do search on Google for "http force to https"

Comment: @Magnetron it doesn't contain app.UseHsts();

Comment: First trace down who sent the 307 response, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Set up your logging to Debug and see when the redirect is happening.

Comment: Does your IIS have rewrite module for https redirection or something like that?

Comment: @Amir The URL Rewrite module is installed, it isn't configured

Comment: Just disable or delete it for testing and recheck!

Comment: @Amir disabling it doesn't work

Comment: @LexLi Failed-Request Tracing or logging doesn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: Do you have something like curl (or somehow) installed to double-check the request and for me? I want the log of response like this: curl [Your Address] -v

Comment: @Amir This is what I get when i run the command 
* Rebuilt URL to: http://api.projectname.dev/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.projectname.dev (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.projectname.dev
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 20:01:41 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host api.projectname.dev left intact

Comment: I can't see any redirection :|. Am I correct?

Comment: The problem was that I was using a .dev domain
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https

Comment: The problem was that I was using a .dev domain
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https

Answer (score -1):

Remove the line UseHttpsRedirection() from your Program or Startup.cs

Comment: The project doesn't contain UseHttpsRedirect()

Comment: Please let us see your appsetting, properties and startup file.

Comment: It should be `UseHttpsRedirection`.

Comment: As you know the dictation of UseHttpsRedirection inside the answer is not such important :| because if it really exists on his code, he can find it! @LexLi

Comment: @LexLi The project also doesn't contain UseHttpsRedirection()

Comment: @studiobram I commented above and asked you to trace down the source of redirection first. It might not come from ASP.NET Core side.