# Angular app running issue in google chrome

Tags: angular, angularjs, google-chrome

I am trying to run angular app and when I type ng serve --open it runs fine but when I run using VS code localhost configuration, it shows localhost refused to connect error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I have following configuration in launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
        "url": "https://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried clearing Chrome cache, checking firewall and trying other settings but it does not work. Browser console does not show any error as well. I tried running on different port but it does not work. In incognito it works but does not hit the debugger at all. What are the other things I can try to make this work in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

More details are needed to know exactly what is happening, here is one possible issue/solution:

When using "localhost" sometimes Chrome defaults to "https" which will cause this error connection refused. Here is a StackOverflow for that: [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https)